# How to loop attributes in a JSON string post converting it into C# object?

Tags: c#, json

I have a below `json`, I want to loop the items inside the attribute `CheckingUrls`.

```
{
  "Root": {
    "Urls": {
      "CheckingUrls": [
        {
          "API Management": {
            "url": ".azure-api.net",
            "displayurl": "*.azure-api.net"
          },
          "Log Analytics": {
            "url": "1.ods.opinsights.azure.com",
            "displayurl": "*.ods.opinsights.azure.com"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here are the C# class

```
public class Root
{
   Urls Urls { get; set; }
}


public class Urls 
{
   public List<CheckingUrls> CheckingUrls { get; set; }
}


public class CheckingUrls
{
    [JsonProperty("API Management")]
    public UrlDetails APIManagement { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Log Analytics")]
    public UrlDetails LogAnalytics { get; set; }

}

public class UrlDetails
{
    [JsonProperty("url")]
    public string url { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("displayurl")]
    public string displayurl { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to convert it into `c#` object using the below code

```
    var content = File.ReadAllText(jsonstring);
    var settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(content);
```

I am getting `APIManagement` and `LogAnalytics` as properties in the result. Is it possible to get these as `List`, so that I can loop the contents without hardcoding the properties in code.

Why I need solution:  We might add new child to `CheckingUrls` and we do not want to change the c# code everytime when we change JSON.

Comment: I'd try to deserialize a `Dictionary<string, UrlDetails>` ...

Comment: ^^ So instead of `public List<CheckingUrls> CheckingUrls { get; set; }` => `public Dictionary<string, UrlDetails> CheckingUrls { get; set; }`

Comment: Are you able to change your JSON schema? Why is `CheckingUrls` a list with a complex object as an element?

Comment: No, I can  NOT change JSON schema. I have to manage somehow in c# code. It was legacy mistake and now can not change

Comment: Oooh, didn't see the curlies ... my suggestion won't work then. Really looks like a Bug to me, though. That doesn't make sense _at all_.

Comment: DeserializeObject should target Root class?    JSON we might add many more child in future and we do not want to change C# code for every new entry in JSON.

Comment: Just a note, and this might have been because of my edit due to the original JSON posted being invalid, but the `CheckingUrls` JSON property is a child of the `Urls` property, which isn't reflected in the C#.

Comment: I have corrected the C# class in question.  @gunr2171 Could you update your answer?

Comment: My answer still stands correct. You claim that your posted code works for hard-coded entries, but I don't agree. You don't have a C# class with a "Root" property to match up with the outermost JSON object. Either way, my answer is fine.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  Accepted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a C# Dictionary when you want to convert a JSON Object to C# when you don't have a concrete type. `CheckingUrls` is already an array, so you end up with

```
public List<Dictionary<string, UrlDetails>> CheckingUrls { get; set; }
```

The key of a Dictionary entry is the property name in the array element (like "API Management"), and the value is the object that contains the `url` and `displayurl` properties.

This eliminates the need for the `CheckingUrls` C# class.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a List, you can create a CheckingUrls class

```
    List<CheckingUrls> checkingUrlsList = JObject.Parse(json)
    .SelectToken("Root.Urls.CheckingUrls")
    .SelectMany(jo => ((JObject)jo).Properties()
    .Select(p => new CheckingUrls
    {
        UrlName = p.Name,
        UrlDetails = new UrlDetails
        {
            url = (string)p.Value["url"],
            displayurl = (string)p.Value["displayurl"]
        }
    }
    )).ToList();

public class CheckingUrls
{
    public string UrlName { get; set; }
    public UrlDetails UrlDetails { get; set; }
}

public class UrlDetails
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string displayurl { get; set; }
}
```

output ( in a json format)

```
[
  {
    "UrlName": "API Management",
    "UrlDetails": {
      "url": ".azure-api.net",
      "displayurl": "*.azure-api.net"
    }
  },
  {
    "UrlName": "Log Analytics",
    "UrlDetails": {
      "url": "1.ods.opinsights.azure.com",
      "displayurl": "*.ods.opinsights.azure.com"
    }
  }
]
```

but if you changed your mind to a Dictionary

```
     Dictionary<string, UrlDetails> checkingUrlsDict = JObject.Parse(json)
    .SelectToken("Root.Urls.CheckingUrls")
    .Select(jo => jo.ToObject<Dictionary<string, UrlDetails>>())
    .FirstOrDefault();
```